# Retrieving allowed values for a column of type SET

Tags: mysql

How do you retrieve the list of allowed values for a table column of type SET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html):

> To determine all possible values for a SET column, use SHOW COLUMNS
>   FROM tbl_name LIKE set_col and parse the SET definition in the Type
>   column of the output.

So, for a table created by:

```
CREATE TABLE myset (col SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

statement:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM myset LIKE 'col'
```

returns:

```
Field, Type,                   Null,  Key, Default, Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------
'col', 'set('a','b','c','d')', 'YES', '',  NULL,    ''
```

You can obtain required info by parsing `Type` column.